# Select HTML element with single class but do not select others with multiple classes?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a component .table-view that has a .table-cell child, and I want to keep my classes clean, how do I select a .table-cell that has no other classes and is a direct descendant of table-view?

Open to any kind of advanced selector that is implemented in relatively new Webkit.

```
<div class="table-view">
    <div class="table-cell">
       <!-- How to select this HTML element without selecting the others? -->
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell split">
        <div class="table-cell">

        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you 'always' want to select just one element, consider using an identifier (`id` attribute).

Comment: if you know it's first element then use `:first-child` selector

Comment: You should specify in what language you want to be able to select it, e.g. CSS, JavaScript, ... If it's JavaScript you're using, I recommend using jQuery, with a selector as follows: `$('.table-cell')`. More info: http://jquery.com/

Comment: In most cases there are propper solutions with simple css defining first more general attributes and then specifying them and maybe overwriting some rules. So maybe it's possible to help you in another way if you tell us what you like to do exactly.

Comment: @Dreamonic He tagged `html` and `css`...

Comment: @Aquillo Woops, I must've skipped that. Nevermind! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use element - attribute selector ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfymv))

```
.table-view > div[class=table-cell] {
  /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: No criticism, just curious: is `div[class=table-cell]` any different from `div.table-cell`?

Comment: @Aquillo Yes, the above selector will select elements having class of `table-cell` only, where `div.table-cell` will select `<div class="table-cell split">` too, which OP doesn't want

Comment: @Aquillo Sorry for late reply, stackoverflow is having issues in India I guess, I pinged and I am receiving timed out

Comment: @xpy Missed out the class, done!Ya I just read after you pointed it out

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [direct descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors) combined with the attribute selector to match exactly again the `class` attribute. The following will match all elements whose parent is `.table-view` where the class attribute is exactly `"table-cell"`.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRPtt/2/)

```
.table-view > [class="table-cell"] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

---

Alternatively you can do this with the  [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anot)

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRPtt/)

```
.table-view > .table-cell:not(.split)
```

This will consider `.table-cell` elements that do not contain the `.split` class but may contain other classes.

Comment: what if he has more classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
div.table-view > div[class="table-cell"] {
    color: #f00;
}
```

That means that class exactly matches "table-cell", with no extras.

You could also use `[class*="table-cell"]`, which means it is contained anywhere in the class attribute, so it would match a class of "table-cell-blargh". You can also use `^=` (begins with) and `$=` (ends with), and you can search any attribute (such as href) using this method.

See [this article on attribute selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Incorrect, it isn't shorthand for `[class*="table-cell"]`, that would also match `.table-cell-blargh` for example.